# How to properly deploy laravel nova on digitalocean apps

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, digital-ocean-apps

I want to deploy a laravel API application that is using nova as a backend on digitalocean app platform. So I have added all environment variables as `App-Level Environment Variables` in app settings including `NOVA_USERNAME` set to my nova emaill and `NOVA_PASSSWRD` set to my nova license key. During the app creation, I am getting the error below

```
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]        Warning from nova.laravel.com: 
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]        
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]        ***************************************************
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]        Unable to find user with the given email address: .
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]        ***************************************************
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]            Failed to download laravel/nova from dist: The 'https://nova.laravel.com/dist/laravel/nova/laravel-nova-f33003b1991491165e8822680e9a827f33c279c5-zip-383f38.zip' URL could not be accessed (HTTP 403): HTTP/2 403 
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]            Now trying to download from source
[2022-07-21 11:43:25]          - Syncing laravel/nova (4.2.1) into cache
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]        
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]        In Git.php line 484:
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]                                                                                       
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@github.com:laravel/nova.git' '  
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          /layers/heroku_php/shim/php/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-laravel-nova  
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          .git/'                                                                       
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]                                                                                       
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          Cloning into bare repository '/layers/heroku_php/shim/php/.composer/cache/v  
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          cs/git-github.com-laravel-nova.git'...                                       
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.121.4'  
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]           to the list of known hosts.                                                 
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).                               
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]                                                                                       
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          Please make sure you have the correct access rights                          
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]          and the repository exists.                                                   
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]                                                                                       
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]        
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]        
[2022-07-21 11:43:27] 
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     in your 'composer.json'.
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
[2022-07-21 11:43:27]  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
[2022-07-21 11:43:27] 
[2022-07-21 11:43:27] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

What is the right way to handle the deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell composer to use the env variables:
`composer config http-basic.nova.laravel.com ${NOVA_USERNAME} ${NOVA_PASSWORD}`

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/nova/how-to-deployment-laravel-nova

Update for heroku:
Add a `COMPOSER_AUTH` env variable with the following value (replace credentials)

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "nova.laravel.com": {
            "username": "foo",
            "password": "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using digitalocean's app platform. How can I tell it to use the set variables?

Comment: If I understand correctly it deploys with heroku, for heroku you can provide a`COMPOSER_AUTH` environment with the composer auth json, updating my answer with an example

Comment: Worked like  a charm. I would never have thought of that, thanks man.